# Partition of a set A where $A= \{0,1\}^3$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $A = \{0, 1\}^3$: that is, $A$ is the set of all ordered triples with entries from 0 and 1.
Then define a relation $R \subseteq A \times A$ such that $xRy$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same number of 0s. Note that $R$ is an equivalence relation.
Give the partition of $A$ created by the equivalence classes of $R$.

I'm going through set partition theory and although I understand the definition of partition, I'm not sure how to be *sure* that all the partitions I have listed are truly all the partitions of a set.

And then I'm not quite sure how to begin thinking about this question. Can anyone help out?

Comment: You're not asked for all the partitions of a set. You're asked for the partition induced by the equivalence relation $R$. And that is the partition into equivalence classes. Pick an element of $A$, find all the other elements of $A$ equivalent to the one you picked, and that's one part of the partition. Now pick another element of $A$, one that's not equivalent to the other(s) you have picked, etc., repeating until all the elemtns of $A$ are accounted for.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalence classes are $$\{(0,0,0)\}$$ $$\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$$ $$\{(1,1,0), (1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$$ $$\{(1,1,1)\}$$

Comment: There is a typo.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't get the typo that Yves Daoust was probably referring to. But I fixed it for you now.

Comment: OP wanted help on how to start thinking about the problem. This looks more like preventing OP from thinking about the problem by doing it all for him/her.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The equivalence classes naturally correspond to the possible numbers of $0$s, namely $0,1,2$ or $3$. So there is a partition in at most four subsets. (I say "at most" in case some of the subsets would be empty.)

Regroup
$$000: 0,001: 1, 010: 1, 011: 2, 100: 1,101: 2, 110: 2, 111: 3.$$